# Problems reading Settings-Watch.bundle in WatchKit

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

I am tearing my hair out trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I suspect it's something simple that I'm missing.

I have set up an app group (let's call it group.foobar) and included it in the settings of both the main app and the watch extension.

In Root.plist in Settings-Watch.bundle (which is included under the main app -- I assume that is correct), I have set the ApplicationGroupContainerIdentifier to "group.foobar".

I have one user preference, with the Identifier set to "lang". The preference setting shows up fine when I view it within the Apple Watch app in the simulator.

But I can't seem to read it in my code. In my main app, I call the following:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.foobar"];

NSString *code = [defaults stringForKey:@"lang"];
```

defaults return a valid pointer to an NSUserDefaults object, but it doesn't seem to be the preferences that I have defined. There is no entry for lang. Instead, it contains tthe following:

```
(lldb) po [defaults dictionaryRepresentation]

{

    AppleITunesStoreItemKinds =     (

        wemix,

        podcast,

        document,

        "software-update",

        newsstand,

        "tv-episode",

        "tv-season",

        software,

        audiobook,

        movie,

        song,

        album,

        tone,

        booklet,

        ringtone,

        artist,

        "podcast-episode",

        "itunes-u",

        mix,

        "music-video",

        eBook

    );

    AppleKeyboards =     (

        "en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY",

        "emoji@sw=Emoji",

        "en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY"

    );

    AppleKeyboardsExpanded = 1;

    AppleLanguages =     (

        en,

        fr,

        de,

        "zh-Hans",

        "zh-Hant",

        ja,

        nl,

        it,

        es,

        "es-MX",

        ko,

        pt,

        "pt-PT",

        da,

        fi,

        nb,

        sv,

        ru,

        pl,

        tr,

        uk,

        ar,

        hr,

        cs,

        el,

        he,

        ro,

        sk,

        th,

        id,

        ms,

        "en-GB",

        "en-AU",

        ca,

        hu,

        vi,

        hi

    );

    AppleLocale = "en_US";

    MSVLoggingMasterSwitchEnabledKey = 0;

    NSInterfaceStyle = macintosh;

    NSLanguages =     (

        en,

        fr,

        de,

        "zh-Hans",

        "zh-Hant",

        ja,

        nl,

        it,

        es,

        "es-MX",

        ko,

        pt,

        "pt-PT",

        da,

        fi,

        nb,

        sv,

        ru,

        pl,

        tr,

        uk,

        ar,

        hr,

        cs,

        el,

        he,

        ro,

        sk,

        th,

        id,

        ms,

        "en-GB",

        "en-AU",

        ca,

        hu,

        vi,

        hi

    );

}
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong???

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Do you have the same App Group checked in both phone and watch app TARGETS > Capabilities > App Groups?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this works for you, too - I have just copied the group id from the Settings Bundle and pasted it into the Suite name string:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.foobar"];
```

I don't know why, but although it's visually the same string, it solved my problem - maybe it's just a solution for me, but you can try it, too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks pi1000.

Actually, I discovered the answer to my problem. I needed to call the method -registerDefaults in order to get the defaults saved so that I could read them. I'm not really clear why this is necessary, but it seems to be.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, when are you calling registerDefaults: and what are you passing as parameter?